# Drawing route on map, with multiple markers, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I did my searching but unfortunately didnt find relevant solution. I want to do it by using **codeigniter google map library**. i am following this
[link](http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/directions)
But it is just showing **starting and ending point**, it's not creating **multiple pins** like

[image]

This is making multiple pins with polyline but i want routing like:

[image]

with multiple pins as shown in **polyline** map picture.. Is it posible to get **multiple directions with multiple pins** ??

I tried it but my trick couldn't work. i tried it by using while loop and i incremented the variable before ending point to make my direction like

1. 1st lat, long : starting point
2. 2nd lat, long : ending point
3. 2nd lat, long : starting point
4. 3rd lat, long : ending point
5. 3rd lat, long : starting point
6. 4th lat, long : ending point

But it's only making 1st and last ending point for start and end direction

Here is my **controller** function

```
##Load library
$this->load->library('googlemaps');

## Getting data from db
     $final_data['final_data'] = $this->Main_manager->getAllEmailLogsById($id);

     $email = $final_data['final_data'][0]['email'];
     $date = $final_data['final_data'][0]['date'];

     $file = 'assets/email_logs/'.$email.'-'.str_replace(' ','-',$date).'.txt';

     ## Getting lat long data from txt file
     $logData = file_get_contents($file); 
     $logData = json_decode($logData, true);

    $marker = array(); 
    $logs = count($logData['logs']);  
    $config['center'] = $final_data['final_data'][0]['lat'].','. $final_data['final_data'][0]['long'];
    $config['zoom'] = 'auto';

    $i=0;
    while($i<$logs-1):
        $config['position'] = $logData['logs'][$i]['lat'].','. $logData['logs'][$i]['long'];
        $config['infowindow_content'] = $logs['email'];
        $config['animation'] = 'DROP';
        $config['draggable'] = FALSE; 
        $config['directions'] = TRUE;
        $config['directionsStart'] =  $logData['logs'][$i]['lat'].','. $logData['logs'][$i]['long'];
        $i++;
        $config['directionsEnd'] = $logData['logs'][$i]['lat'].','. $logData['logs'][$i]['long'];
        $config['directionsDivID'] = 'directionsDiv'; 
    endwhile; 

    ## initialize the map
    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

    ##create map
    $final_data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

    $this->load->view('administrator/header');
    $this->load->view('administrator/view_logs_detail', $final_data);
```

Comment: Wth?? why downvote my question without commenting about what is wrong with my question ?

Comment: If someone wants to downvote this question, you can but please specify the valid reason for downvote.

Comment: follow this link,

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints

Comment: i want to do it by using codeigniter google map api library, don't want to use external javascript ... this link is based on javascript but it's pretty good if i won't get any solution, i'll go throught this one. Thanks @Mr.J

Comment: please see this, you might get what you are looking for...

https://github.com/BIOSTALL/CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library/blob/master/application/libraries/Googlemaps.php#L130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you need to use [google's DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions).
This service Google map API key to draw routes
Get google key from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) login to google account and generate key for your project

[**Working Demo**](http://codepen.io/nomantraffic/pen/yaQWOY)

HTML

```
<h1>Google Map direction service</h1>
<div id="map"></div>
```

CSS

```
html,
    body,
    #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
    }
```

JS:

```
var map;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var locations = [
    ['Shahrah-e-Faisal, Karachi, Pakistan', 24.8678, 67.0842, 1],
    ['Tariq Rd, Karachi, Pakistan', 24.8727, 67.0604, 2],
    ['Service Lane, Karachi, Pakistan', 24.8161, 67.0212, 3]
];

function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.8678, 67.0842),
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
    var request = {
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        if (i == 0) request.origin = marker.getPosition();
        else if (i == locations.length - 1) request.destination = marker.getPosition();
        else {
            if (!request.waypoints) request.waypoints = [];
            request.waypoints.push({
                location: marker.getPosition(),
                stopover: true
            });
        }

    }
    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```